# ubuntu 11.10 and external monitor not recognized

Tags: 11.10, wubi, display, external-monitor

I have a laptop and it's being a nightmare to properly set up an external monitor I use.
I had ubuntu 11.10 installed through wubi and it worked as I wanted, I started the laptop with the lid closed and the image automatically went to the monitor.

Later I decided to format my pc and used the opportunity to properly install ubuntu on a separate partition, as i might need more than the 30Gb that wubi imposes. After this ubuntu can no longer recognize the plugged monitor (doesn't even show up on the display settings) and the laptop monitor is shown as 'unknown'.

I tried installing the nvidia recommended drivers and tried to use the nvidia tool to set up the monitors. I was able to put the image only on the external monitor, but when I unplug it I get no image at all on my laptop.

After this I tried a lot of uninstalling and reinstalling ubuntu with no success, though the funny thing is that I found out that if I start ubuntu in a bootable pen (that 'try ubuntu' option) it works fine, it detects the displays properly.

Between this and all the OS reinstalls I managed to render my Windows7 unbootable and though I now have fixed that, right now I don't have ubuntu installed and I'm hopping that if I install wubi again I might solve this problem, though I would like to know if there is something I could try if I actually reinstall it again or if I better just install wubi and use some workaround to increase it's space.

It seems like a joke that such a simple task as plugging a screen can give so many problems to solve.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi shouldn't be any different to a normal install. You may reinstall it and find that it doesn't work either. I think it'd be better to just work on your actual problem. In my opinion.

If you do go with Wubi, then I'd recommend synchronized, real time backups. Any data stored on the virtual disk is contained within a single file and it's a higher risk running a loop file system than on a partition.

The only differences between Wubi and a normal install is I believe you get the option to install closed source drivers during the normal install.

One last thing, if you still have that working Wubi install backed up, you can [migrate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi) it to a normal install (from the `root.disk`) and that gives you an identical install to your Wubi install, except no virtual disk.